# Exception in ListFragment: The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

I'm making a downloader app, and i got child's parents error after the onCreateView return section.
I tried a lots of things, but nothing help. I tried:
`((ViewGroup)dlistView.getParent()).removeView(dlistView);`
after that the compiler says:

```
01-12 12:05:15.558: E/AndroidRuntime(10740): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

or remove the container/ i got an npe/ or remove the V but the V.getParent() is null.

> Which view is the parent, and which is the child?

The code:

```
public static class DownloadingFragment extends ListFragment {
public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        public DownloadingFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View V = inflater.inflate (R.layout.list, null);    
            ListView dlistView = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.dlist);
            List<DownloadInfo> downloadInfo = new ArrayList<DownloadInfo>();
            downloadInfo.add(new DownloadInfo("File", 1000));
            DownloadInfoArrayAdapter diaa = new DownloadInfoArrayAdapter(
                    getActivity().getApplication(),R.layout.list, downloadInfo);
            dlistView.setAdapter(diaa);
        return dlistView; // throw exception 
        }
    }
//...
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT:
the new code:

```
public static class DownloadingFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        public DownloadingFragment() {
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View V = inflater.inflate (R.layout.list, null);    
        return V;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onStart();
            ListView dlistView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.dlist);
            List<DownloadInfo> downloadInfo = new ArrayList<DownloadInfo>();
            downloadInfo.add(new DownloadInfo("File", 1000));
            DownloadInfoArrayAdapter diaa = new DownloadInfoArrayAdapter(
                    getActivity().getApplication(),R.layout.list, downloadInfo);
            dlistView.setAdapter(diaa);
        }
    }
//...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you return the listview which has a parent (somewhere in V's layout tree) .

for any type of fragment , onCreateView should return a view that doesn't have any parent .

in this case , since it's a listFragment , create the listview (either using xml or programmatically ) , and then return it . do not allow it to have any parents since it needs to have a parent as a fragment .

read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for more information :

> The system calls this when it's time for the fragment to draw its
>   user interface for the first time. To draw a UI for your fragment, you
>   must **return a View from this method that is the root** of your
>   fragment's layout. You can return null if the fragment does not
>   provide a UI.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the third argument of inflate is false.
so replace this line

```
View V = inflater.inflate (R.layout.list, null);
```

with this

```
View V = inflater.inflate (R.layout.list, null,false);
```

and you are done.hope this helps.